# React nested state update

Tags: reactjs

I want to update a nested state which contains an array in React app.

I want do update this nested state ***data*** attribute I have use
to update to update labels

```
this.setState(prevState => 
    ({
      datas: {
        ...prevState.datas,
        labels: this.state.responseToPost.mois,
       
      }
    }));
```

but when I use this for data:

```
let key = 0;
this.setState(prevState => ({

    datas: prevState.datas.datasets.map(
    el => el.key === key? { ...el, data: this.state.responseToPost.taux }: el
  )
}))
```

this is the nested state I want update with a handler

```
datas: {
        labels: [],//this.state.dataLabel,
        datasets: [
          {
           //
           //some param
            data: []
          }
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I get your example, as the variables' names aren't consistent.

However I think what you're looking for is the `...` operator, that "fills" an array or an object with the "content" of another.

For example, I first defined an object - and then defined a new object, containing the same `constant` parameters, but with a different value of `shouldBeChanged` parameter.

```js
var obj = {
  constant0: 0,
  constant1: 1,
  shouldBeChanged: 'old value'
};

// Here I only change a single nested parameter
var newObj = {...obj,
  shouldBeChanged: 'new value'
};

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

## How use this expression to update a state array object

In my research I found a use case for this expression.
I did not use the expression before because @GalAbra's answer solved my problem.
So Im come back to tell what I have understand about this following expression :

```
let key = 0; // providing id
this.setState(prevState => ({

    datas: prevState.datas.datasets.map(
    el => el.key === key? { ...el, data: this.state.responseToPost.taux }: el
  )
}))
```

#### When we can use this

I came back to this message when ***I wanted to update an object contained in an object state array from the object's id***. I took this syntax as an example and wrote this.

```
dataStruc :[] // state  containing objects

updatObj // updated object 

this.setState(prevState=>({
  dataStruc:prevState.dataStruc.map(el=>( el.id!== updObj.id ? {...el} : updatObj))   
    }));
```